# jmeter token request "invalid_grant" wit duende identity server 4

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter, identityserver4

i´m writing an jmeter test and cannot get an successfull token request with jmeter.
May someone has an idea whats the mistake? I always get "invalid_grant" after the POST request for an access token.

THe authentication itself 2 steps before wit an POST request with username and passwort works normal and i get an "302 FOUND" Response.

The "code" for the POST request is requested on step after the login POST and i´m getting the "code" at the response url, exracting it as an var_code and insert it to the POST Request to getting the tokens. If needed i can post it buti think the problem is here.

I analyzed both POSTS with fiddler but cannot find the problem.

This ist the POST from Jmeter for requesting the id_token and request_token.

Because of different requests please ignore the differences in code and Cookie-Data of this 2 POSTs.

```
POST https://webdev.mydomain.de/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Host: webdev.mydomain.de
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Origin: https://webdev.mydomain.de
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://webdev.mydomain.de/authentication/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwebdev.mydomain.de%2F
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ojWZJgwSQZ4=CfDJ8Ii7hfs2C-pAlOJaWOSnm_0TL6Q3H7bnVABRJNul9dTxs4WshEhgw_nHH4Y5KH8aVq1G3bzPiew87yWYvESI3kJv49NqvWralIJc277fFiH7s5l2od1ltxQyhOgbFyzzxt9Z0x_wvK_VnaqC_ZqyBxs; idsrv.session=1B06321E516DF9D2EAC1E6F959A278D4; SessionId=7d687c9d-f417-4419-b043-ef6f6ba07fe6; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8Ii7hfs2C-pAlOJaWOSnm_22yBAvy-61YgdEYkWj2a9zdmchhG9a_BgYyG3Dh6qf4jto73b4Xopv67KmdXh1K8zIwIAgk8HLwzIlJpmOZdUxtQHMylF7vAB7ljurSpnaJUBX7R1D8naDFA6ieqD9w6hgYp8leweX-M9a4PJUQX6339wdp_EDjYgT5Bl-kCDMYfMv1sPlPpFfJAW6rh64Iz1kbH3IWjFrrxzZ5mtb46d1FO-xBF8Dpqs_7Wf_Azv1Ne4TDM8XSevVk6IVMoxaz0c2e_UimE4DxYjqAhvJJm8Tnawzd8W3BqimPAQckS73d4AWzohKjCWaHWXn2KaqkGXXGqdQxyfIImSg5IGV4kEr8w2IwJLjYkfz829r1hEAkiuy_O59iaZWSeS56eFzh0Sy-PJZYtNm-kQ8NsZNldquV4_b05CXcmd9Cyj8sMZXIKIMlrlWwchsW4E1Dm4rYQ6hbfY0Lq6dlzdATWKIyRS-Upl2J_d6nN0_UePsg_QtK_lTo2MiKGXGINkQHd6bTnbyJ6EDds9fzvUxUABtkHwyr7d5q6a8iHK6gqLJfLNUIPKpwwev9G3J-G_m-r3iGO57A7Tt_7HoKNNlOnuLDrcyhOZwsmHnQrom8cvaU8Zip97ZQGCy01U9Lz1fqn-B-VQ0GxnWcBEvMkRZ_ozwhcDt6MS-MmcWsBfhr71uSxHrspWjNKt6-X-ILir0DL_Y6u7lb4ZDYqtDuOx1cB82Ohv4DHfBmaoAQlmgWzfvY1Fs58rp9qAfd2jMuEBDSv6RFz_ATBi5GL9eZrKReLdNn4prxGGQbuj9OUOBGa88NRIuDxbxsbLRdzUUtr0yMo-pf0eYZMovaYdiwSmnGqDZ7JtD7ftc0c0e4M3s9e1hfr3w3ApaikkczYANa9JCCMKCBIXy2XBTPUPfhfWObUoHlq0r9fGAx_1l2v2fGDb6n4jsRqI55xBDzMzk6KAiZhD5AKVPgV3FtotkD1vD3I37ZIC1
Content-Length: 259

client_id=webapp&code=BB460C6A509179386BC2C4F282F2205A239303BC8AEDA57C0D7B135D90FF80B1-1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebdev.mydomain.de%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&code_verifier=OAHVC8ZKbbWUXaNKXXHjfiM5QgP6nTH3Vs40A7m9TOc&grant_type=authorization_code
```

and the response with failure

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 May 2023 08:53:58 GMT

19
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
0
```

This is the POST from the original Web-Applikation

```
POST https://webdev.mydomain.de/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: webdev.mydomain.de
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 312
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
Origin: https://webdev.mydomain.de
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: https://webdev.mydomain.de/authentication/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwebdev.mydomain.de%2F
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.ojWZJgwSQZ4=CfDJ8Ii7hfs2C-pAlOJaWOSnm_0sPzX9_JBekQ9lD_EhcTyuNrsAW07eUAhDXCj71lowqtZXsya4ivGnQb1921zyp-s641YDkHB1L7Ig8mKosYZHNzBdsikhMI6RQyHvtutNwEa-ZZHZ1QpNbc9NdcxCrs4; idsrv.session=141B3D26CA7E6065BCA136684B9BD71D; SessionId=be634c3a-f521-40af-89ec-7cd0e582f0bf; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8Ii7hfs2C-pAlOJaWOSnm_3pL7jbF5erpuUmAtIKVc7g34lOzQ3oGoD603czvybpIR0Tx1BGwrKF5IcT7BGTUOTSBJNcKeDtAsYhALW-CEJoshghYKZ4fxyiW584pad4wvtQbgiIBGPHvvQ4xJMZ9aLeu5ITnChVi_82rowIzMAuWqKtTischCVXHFPgX15drFCHHsv0qQg36HGGcmeri0SfrYC6YIUiMCH4PrKjJWFkNnPwoXd7YEQbmPd0c4E0HBqmDn2w539SH1LgOYg7kMMIczAFg2HfXH84PXD1TEQjpMcshbKlDWy0cHVVrMYupfDujnM_w11OMY7A5BoxN1p9fAxW0bem6TtCmhphMyvuouXu7pttSmy0PzXouWqS2eeNQsewF5wnChG0dlnYZMvfzP7GoQLittlbhWWxMjtWMsgtHcVFMVnNMPzmO0FCKFRJR5hYv-IHwgYy0syZfqdauxo-JnYjjT8DEGI5hINAotwkhVur9uCQfeZM5n1B3GoMK_GsPhx8IxCEp_BoeDnL9Ja5yC93cDMKlHUu_kt7OPxfvpiHrWQbScDkOn6V3VxZiU13uUqm6aXVKq6ZouvfBfSphACCKg2aqjlo2mumh6c5U21EK2Xz56lDFwbUJueO2s_VTjHoNmUTiMwlLSbfiVgNxOQVD-OqfLlFDgNpV46DG_EScKoA0w75uARfeTHhC_LEoZ-ibZ5UWMSMPNzsja2TrSMOtr2T74iQGa_HhGylzJyQHMGYVOs-wizjSZc5K0kyCbPw4IdZ7J8-EehzJ6DAhDtlu2u5yr8zPnp_F7A8mf9zJMUlTs2mXt03Xo4n5o3PIwSL_7LvOrd7gHlEXOuMJbtnukm1WEVL33Njjdvcmgkg37vsK9N4zOqEGiOIsnDyZNOCEnqpqqcjPcFobIMtrmH1scKiQGZQiLNxGBpfou6_MTXLIyngzZdk9k017JWwnFX54gQlCPR_ZI98FFQmzADxsDu7XNRg5pTC

client_id=webapp&code=66CCD684F12CA6B1E1D5315FDC848CD7B49A306A0C951B9FAA57E1EBC41CB26E-1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwebdev.mydomain.de%2Fauthentication%2Flogin-callback&code_verifier=3a88975adbf64d48a7a16f66303c4a58bc8d04d246834fc5b19cf75b90a571d0acc6e818138448a0af9b9e12532cc056&grant_type=authorization_code
```

And the Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 04 May 2023 08:56:43 GMT

6e8
{"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkRldmVsb3BtZW50IiwidHlwIjoiSldUIn0.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3dpc2Rldi5sdWtyYS10aXYuZGUiLCJuYmYiOjE2ODMxOTA2MDQsImlhdCI6MTY4MzE5MDYwNCwiZXhwIjoxNjgzMTkwOTA0LCJhdWQiOiJXaXNlbnRybyIsImFtciI6WyJwd2QiXSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IkQ5QjZ3NHVLemtCZnhocXJmQkJ2UkEiLCJzaWQiOiIxNDFCM0QyNkNBN0U2MDY1QkNBMTM2Njg0QjlCRDcxRCIsInN1YiI6ImY2ZTdlNTZmLWNhMmYtNDVmZC1lZDYzLTA4ZGIzY2Q2NDUzOSIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTY4MzE5MDYwMywiaWRwIjoibG9jYWwifQ.IvZWPtEegQdBURxG-mkDoPnDfVusTH8e9E_X-lKtrFrpTiVqItZp5GMph5dmQt71QNBiwg5S5aJpH_rZ7vCJujhpimgG5ydAJBorta4EE2xKgWhA9sH-90Kxe27M1QL4tFgM9ceyQF3P9YhyuqkXbM5l3XpelGP0JELVL3e6fyuRUoVfTrqVD7vWLaVw9MheqmYaYlpDWQ2xez0MdBDrpDQgiFpaxmi7DmcxU1asp7p2WUC8bfvrnOjhBoHo_Nh3D4anGRHXa9rOmDJ6YulBCarmURKc7LLOkqbjsojVUfhwCvUa5kVne2op5354Gjt0-Qy2ymetnFxw0g1wXI7IWA","access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkRldmVsb3BtZW50IiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3dpc2Rldi5sdWtyYS10aXYuZGUiLCJuYmYiOjE2ODMxOTA2MDQsImlhdCI6MTY4MzE5MDYwNCwiZXhwIjoxNjgzMTk0MjA0LCJhdWQiOiJXaXNlbnRyb0FQSSIsInNjb3BlIjpbIldpc2VudHJvQVBJIiwib3BlbmlkIiwicHJvZmlsZSJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Ildpc2VudHJvIiwic3ViIjoiZjZlN2U1NmYtY2EyZi00NWZkLWVkNjMtMDhkYjNjZDY0NTM5IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjgzMTkwNjAzLCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInNpZCI6IjE0MUIzRDI2Q0E3RTYwNjVCQ0ExMzY2ODRCOUJENzFEIiwianRpIjoiODM2Q0NGRjhCNTQzMDc5N0EzODUzQzc5NjBDRTgxRjcifQ.Q3eytFv7kXlwPFeeoXFF8Pw3paIUQoShQDdv_TtdrSW_u-ED_ESwbUuq2m94dHzOl8UrVNhHe39R59n43DSrPLKnIpNkciA6en_jyO_tI1YOc8fq_jLQQBio0u-IQkf0q8j12lrkqVV1lMeAUB3G1x83NgtMKPCQxGtFc6hLzWzxCXBOLwqGJO8LFM_ydwozTYOtDxwSX23Lzzf11KdTSoZTJbtIFWboaLnWnPz8tKg-aMa3ZAZymOt_V8_KZEAnf02mC1GmDvGic6msV-2wzBB9d6wtLslJjxSr7NQtxKuZ-fCcGqlcupXJvyXWmZpjY7fbLpduSnDaf6u2uJR0hg","expires_in":3600,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"webappAPI openid profile"}
0
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first glance there are 2 major differences:

1. JMeter sends `client_id=webapp`
2. Browser sends `client_id=webentro`

If the value comes from correlation - double check your [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and the variable holding the extracted value, you can see what [variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are defined with their respective values using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

Otherwise just set it to `webentro` and my expectation is that the problem will go away.

Comment: Sorry, that was an mistake to anonymize the data. in both original requests the client-id=webapp